# Django app not displaying data in template

Tags: python, html, django

im brand new to Django and attempting to make my first ECommerce site. I'm attempting to get a list of products from a .JSON file to display in my products.html template. The products are in place, as shown in the Django admin portal, `products`is definied with in my `views.py` file and i've done `loaddata` but nothing comes through. I've added some screenshots and code below to further explain.

**Views.py Code:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product


def all_products(request):

    products = Product.objects.all()

    context = {
        'products': products,
    }

    return render(request, 'products/products.html', context)
```

**products.html Template:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block page_header %}
<div class="container header-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{ products }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

My folder structure is correct but I'll post it here just incase:
[image]
Any help would be great as i've been stuck with this for a while now. Thanks!

**models.py:***

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the object you are passing to your template.
For example,

```
{% for product in products %}
    <img src={{ product.src }} />
    <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ product.desc }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done most of the thing right so far. One thing that causes the issue is the template didn't iterate all the products.

In the views.py, Product.objects.all() returns a query set which you can imagine it is a list that contains many product instances.

So when the products, which is Product.objects.all(), is passed to template, you will need to use a loop to iterate the instances inside the products.

I assume your product model contains the following three fields(you can replace them with the actual field inside your product model later in the example I provide).

- name
- description
- qty

Now, in Django template, you can replace the {{ products }} with the following code.

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="text-nowrap"><span>Product</span></th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-nowrap"><span>Description</span></th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-nowrap"><span>Qty</span></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for product in products %}
        <tr>
            <td><span>{{ product.name }}</span></td><!-- Replace the name with your actual field -->
            <td><span>{{ product.desciption }}</span></td><!-- Replace the desciption with your actual field -->
            <td><span>{{ product.qty }}</span></td><!-- Replace the qty with your actual field -->
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With the above example, the most important part is

```
{% for product in products %}
    <tr>
        <td><span>{{ product.name }}</span></td>
        <td><span>{{ product.desciption }}</span></td>
        <td><span>{{ product.qty }}</span></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

It is similar to the following python code.

```
for product in products:
    print(product.name)
    print(product.desciption)
    print(product.qty)
```

And as a result, now the template should show the product on a table.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This was my original approach but it seems that Django is having an issue with rendering the template completely

Comment: I appreciate it. It would be better if you could provide me with some more info about it. So did you use the code above and replace name, description and qty with your actual field? When you said there is an issue with rendering the template, what is the issue look like? Also, it would be more clear if you could provide me with a screenshot of this issue.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code for the model. The weird thing about the template is i dont get the typical Django Template not found error.

Comment: The model looks perfect. You could replace the provided code with your field. For the Template not found error, there is a lot of reasons that cause this issue, one of the reason is the template path is not set properly in the settings.py and would need extra info such as the error page to specify the problem. But that is out of the scope to this post title. I would suggest opening another post for this specific issue.

Comment: Some extra info may help the template not found error. Make sure you have set the 'DIR' within the TEMPLATES inside settings.py. Most of the case, the value of the key 'DIR' should be [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]. So you should have something like this in your settings.py. Ex: TEMPLATES = [ .... 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], .... ]